# Java inhertiance of private fields

Tags: java, inheritance, private, encapsulation, protected

I know that subclass has no access to private field other than with public setter/getter of super-class. I do not have any experience with object-oriented languages so far. Should I make all fields private and just use public method to access them in sub-classes, or make them protected and use the freely in subclasses and package?

Comment: getter/setter access is more traditional in Java. Making objects as less mutable as possible is also very good practice. After a year of experience, you'll understand why.

Comment: Ok, so make all things private and use with setters getters even in its own child classer is kind of socially acceptable way?

Comment: If you make solid package, of course there is no need to do so, but make sure all this fields are hidden from direct access from out of the package. "Getters/setters everywhere" are more about JPA, EJB and other enterprise stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Make them `protected`. This is the sole purpose why this keyword exists!

Comment: Not really. It depends on whether the OP care about leaking the internal state or not.

Answer (score 1):

In `OOP` there is a feature `encapsulation` and `encapsulation` strongly suggest us to hide data from the outer world. And you can hide data by making field/property/variable private.

And for accessing the private variable use some public `getter` method.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your needs. If you need access to subclass as well as the same package, make it `protected`.

Here are the general rules:

`private`: class access only.

`protected`: package access and also derived classes.

`default`: same package only.

`public`: anyone can access it.

Answer (score 0):

> A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.
>
> A nested class has access to all the private members of its enclosing
>   class—both fields and methods. Therefore, a public or protected nested
>   class inherited by a subclass has indirect access to all of the
>   private members of the superclass.

[See the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: @chancea Look at the title he talks about inheritance

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP is asking about a design issue not the rules around scope.